# can you iterate over a vector within a while statement?

Tags: c++, while-loop

is there a way to iterate over a vector within a while statement?

for example:

```
int R; // number of r types
int T; // number of instances
std::vector<double> r_max (R); // maximum value for each r type
std::vector<std::vector> > r_use (T, std::vector<double>(R)); // value for each instance of each r type

while(all instances of each r type is greater than its corresponding r_max value){
    run_function(r_use);
}
```

the long version of what i want it to do is:

```
int R; // number of r types
int T; // number of instances
std::vector<double> r_max (R); // maximum value for each r type
std::vector<std::vector<double> > r_use (T, std::vector<double>(R)); // value for each instance of each r type

bool flag = false;

while(!flag){
    flag = true;
    for (int r = 0; r < R && flag; ++r){
        for (int t = 0; t < T && flag; ++t){
            if (r_use[t][r] > r_max[r]){
                flag = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!flag){
        run_function(r_use);
    }
}
```

is there a way to do this all in the one while statement? or do i need to iterate over all of the instances and types?

Comment: it would only hide loop inside function.

Comment: The question would be clearer if the two vector declarations were valid C++.

Comment: is that better?

Comment: @guskenny83 .. no .. `std::vector<r_max> (R);` .. That redefines `R` from an `int` to a `std::vector<r_max>`, and what is `r_max`? Are you wanting a map instead: `std::map<int, double> r_max`?

Comment: @guskenny83 you should provide [mcve], you current snip would not compile.

Comment: do you think `while(std::all_of(r_use.begin(),r_use.end(),[&r_max](auto& rs){return std::all_of(rs.begin(),rs.end(),[&,start=rs.data()](auto& d){return d>r_max[&d-start];});})){run_function(r_use);}////:P////` more clear than simple nested loop? well, you should write a function.

Comment: @txtechhelp - sorry! i was completely blind for some reason.. i have fixed it now..

Comment: @appleapple, yeah, i suspected that might be the case. however, i thought it worthwhile at least asking the question in case there was a simple way to do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write a function to do this (here I use a lambda, you can also use normal function)

---

```
auto condition=[&]{
   for(auto& r:r_use)
      for(int i=0;i<R;++i)
         if(r[i]<=r_max[i])
            return false;
   return true;
};
while(condition())run_function(r_use);
```

---

or you can (better not) use algorithm library like this (just implement your first snip)

```
while(std::all_of(r_use.begin(),r_use.end(),[&r_max](auto& rs){
         return std::all_of(rs.begin(),rs.end(),[&,start=rs.data()](auto& d){ 
            return d>r_max[&d-start];});})
)run_function(r_use);
```